# Function messed up with WP admin footer (FLOATING)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, footer, issue-tracking

When I added this function:

```
function woocommerce_add_color_custom(){ ?>

<div class="form-field">
    <label for="display_type"><?php _e( 'Display type', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select name="custom_color_woocommerce" id="custom_color_woocommerce" style="width: 300px;">
        <?php
            $selected = $wccolor;
            $p = '';
            $r = '';

            foreach ( _s_sample_select_options() as $option ) {
                $label = $option['label'];
                if ( $selected == $option['label'] ) // Make default first in list
                    $p .= "\n\t<option style=\"padding-right: 10px;\" selected='selected' value='" . esc_attr( $option['label'] ) . "'>$label</option>";
                else
                    $r .= "\n\t<option style=\"padding-right: 10px;\" value='" . esc_attr( $option['label'] ) . "'>$label</option>";
            }
            echo $p . $r;
        ?></select>
</select>

            <p class="description">Vyberte kategóriu, ktorá sa najviac zhoduje s Woocommerce kategóriou.</p>
</div>

<?
}

add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'woocommerce_edit_color_custom',10,2);
```

It messed up my admin option page :( I do not why and how to solve this problem. Maybe will help ob_clen() but I do not know how and where to use it. I red some articles, but still not sure about it.

Pic with messed up WP admin option page and WP footer:

[image]

Comment: `<div id="main">` solved my problem :)

Comment: this is working only on my plugin admin page :( not on category page...

Comment: There's a double `</select>` in the HTML.

Comment: After removed `</select>` it is still floating :( When I remove this function, all back to normal. But I need this to run.

Answer (score 0):

I found, what is causing it:

```
colors-fresh.min.css:1
#wpfooter { 
border-bottom-color: #DFDFDF;
border-left-color: #DFDFDF;
border-right-color: #DFDFDF;
border-top-color: #DFDFDF;
color: #777777;
}
load-styles.php:2
#wpfooter { 
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 10px 0px;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

When I remove `left: 0px;` footer will disappear. I done this on Opera Dragonfly. But how to repare it and where, I do not know :(

Comment: `position: relative;` also helped me, but only little :(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to your style-sheet, or at the top of your page:

```html
<style>
  #wpfooter {
   display: none;
  }
</style>
```